# Dynamic selection according to the calendar week

Tags: vba, excel, dynamic

I have a team sheet and I need to report the forecast for the next week every Friday via Email.

[image: ExcelSheet]

I built a macro which is creating an email.

```vb
Sub SendMail()

    Dim rng As Range
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Dim VBAWeekNum As Integer

    Set rng = Nothing
    On Error Resume Next
    'Only the visible cells in the selection
    
    Set rng = Sheets("Availability List").Range("A1:C7, D1:J7").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    
    On Error GoTo 0

    If rng Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "The selection is not a range or the sheet is protected" & _
               vbNewLine & "please correct and try again.", vbOKOnly
        Exit Sub
    End If

    With Application
        .EnableEvents = False
        .ScreenUpdating = False
    End With

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

    On Error Resume Next
    With OutMail
        .To = "x@test.de"
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = "X"
        .HTMLBody = "Guten Tag Herr X," & vbCrLf & "anbei wie besprochen die Übersicht für die kommende Woche." & vbCrLf & "Vielen Dank im Voraus." & vbCrLf & "Mit freundlichen Grüßen X" & RangetoHTML(rng)
        .Display 'or use .sent
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0

    With Application
        .EnableEvents = True
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With

    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing
End Sub

Function RangetoHTML(rng As Range)

    Dim fso As Object
    Dim ts As Object
    Dim TempFile As String
    Dim TempWB As Workbook

    TempFile = Environ$("temp") & "\" & Format(Now, "dd-mm-yy h-mm-ss") & ".htm"

    'Copy the range and create a new workbook to past the data in
    rng.Copy
    Set TempWB = Workbooks.Add(1)
    With TempWB.Sheets(1)
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=8
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, , False, False
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats, , False, False
        .Cells(1).Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        On Error Resume Next
        .DrawingObjects.Visible = True
        .DrawingObjects.Delete
        On Error GoTo 0
    End With

    'Publish the sheet to a htm file
    With TempWB.PublishObjects.Add( _
         SourceType:=xlSourceRange, _
         Filename:=TempFile, _
         Sheet:=TempWB.Sheets(1).Name, _
         Source:=TempWB.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Address, _
         HtmlType:=xlHtmlStatic)
        .Publish (True)
    End With

    'Read all data from the htm file into RangetoHTML
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set ts = fso.GetFile(TempFile).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)
    RangetoHTML = ts.readall
    ts.Close
    RangetoHTML = Replace(RangetoHTML, "align=center x:publishsource=", _
                          "align=left x:publishsource=")

    'Close TempWB
    TempWB.Close savechanges:=False

    'Delete the htm file we used in this function
    Kill TempFile

    Set ts = Nothing
    Set fso = Nothing
    Set TempWB = Nothing
End Function
```

Now I would like to automate the whole process. Therefore the range

```
Set rng = Sheets("Availability List").Range("A1:C7,D1:J7").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
```

is not correctly defined. I would like that the second part

`D1:J7").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)` is moving according to the actual calendar week.

E.g. this week it should select the CW13 (means K1:Q7).

Comment: What happens to week 12 once week 13 begins? Do you delete the columns and shift the numbers over?

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using `Range("A1:C7, D1:J7")`, define separate range variables in which the second range (`r2`) can be offset as needed according to the value of i=0,1,2...

The code would look something like this

```
dim r as range, r1 as range, r2 as range, i as integer
set r1=range("A1:C7")
set r2=range("D1:J7")
set r = range(r1,r2.offset(0,7*i))
```

Answer (score 0):

Are the week number cells merged cells?  If so Use `OFFSET` and `MATCH` and `WEEKNUM`  so base around `OFFSET(MATCH(WEEKNUM(TODAY())`

Answer (score 0):

First define a weeknumber variable. You can do this with =WEEKNUM(TODAY())
Lets say this variable is called x.
Then I would continue like this

```
Set rng1 = Sheets("Availability List").Range(Cells(1,1),Cells(7,3)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
Set rng2 = Sheets("Availability List").Range(Cells(1,x),Cells(7,x+6)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
```

Answer (score 0):

you could try

```
    With Sheets("Availability List")
        Set rng = Union(.Range("A1:C7"), _
                        .Rows(2).Find(what:=WorksheetFunction.WeekNum(Date), LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole).Offset(-1).Resize(7)). _
                        SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    End With
```

Answer (score 0):

The following line will pick up your range based on the week number:

```
Set Rng = [2:2].Find(Application.WorksheetFunction.WeekNum(Date)).Resize(1, 7)
```

It works by searching Row 2 for the weeknumber and then offseting by 7 to capture the whole weeks range.

The only word of caution I would give is to ensure that the return of week number matches your definition of week number but this can be alter using the argument as detailed [here](https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/weeknum-function-e5c43a03-b4ab-426c-b411-b18c13c75340).

Also I would change `[2:2]` to a more robust reference to the row based on the sheets in question.

If you need to move past this year eg into week 53 then I would also add in an offset based on the year, although I would assume that you would not have more than 52 weeks of data in the one sheet.

Answer (score 0):

Use Intersect on the rows over the merge area columns.

```
Dim wn As Long, rng As Range
wn = 13
With Sheets("Availability List")
    Set rng = Union(.Range("A1:C7"), _
                    Intersect(.Rows("1:7"), .Cells(2, Application.Match(wn, .Rows(2), 0)).MergeArea.EntireColumn))
    Debug.Print rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Address
End With
```

I'n unclear on why specialcells is necessary. Your helper function may have to be adjusted to work with areas.